# Solved: How do I install new Intel HDA sound drivers: what's "the right location?"

Tags: drivers, dpkg, dkms, hda-intel

This is a followup to another question with this same title, which has one answer, wherein the knowledgeable one says: "Save the file to disk, open a terminal window, change to the right directory and execute 'sudo dpkg -i'".  My question is: how does one determine "the right directory?"  I can't seem to find the answer in the docs and man pages on my installation, or with more than ten hours of googling.  Anyone care to enlighten?  Fwiw, I'm running trusty.

I've edited this query to more accurately quote the instructions that had me confused.  Being more familiar with tarballs than with .deb files, I had assumed that the contents of the .deb file would be placed relative to my current directory, the one from which I executed dpkg.  It seems the instructions meant to say: "...change to the directory where you saved the .deb file..." or they could have simply said: "...execute dpkg -i *pathname-to-.deb-file*".

Thanks for clearing that up; I'm glad I didn't waste any more time chasing down another blind alley.

jimo

Comment: If this is solved, click the check mark by the answer that helped you the most. It gives you reputation and helps the community at the same time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "right location" for the `.deb` file. The `.deb` file is a software package, and contains instructions that are used to install stuff in the "right locations" when you do the `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/any/place/foo.deb`.